# Untraceable exception in XAudio dll

Tags: c++, xaudio2

I'm developing a game using OpenGL and XAudio 2.9. For some reason I am getting an exception in release builds inside the XAudio dll. Here is the exception :

Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBB5416EF1 (XAudio2_9.dll) in Eclipse.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000002AE0FF1B8A8.

I've tried everything from zeroing memory before assigning something to it to initializing all properties to an initial value (since in the debug version I never have crashes). I'm also using mutexes for multithreading safety...

Anyone that has faced something similar and how did you solve it?

Code:

```
SoundSystem::SoundSystem()
{
    UINT32 flags = 0;
#if defined _DEBUG || defined NDEBUG
    flags |= XAUDIO2_DEBUG_ENGINE;
#endif
    DXCall(CoInitialize(nullptr));
    DXCall(XAudio2Create(&pEngine, flags));
#if defined _DEBUG || defined NDEBUG
    pEngine->SetDebugConfiguration(
        new XAUDIO2_DEBUG_CONFIGURATION
        {
            XAUDIO2_LOG_ERRORS | XAUDIO2_LOG_WARNINGS | XAUDIO2_LOG_INFO,
            XAUDIO2_LOG_ERRORS | XAUDIO2_LOG_WARNINGS,
            true, true, true, true
        }
    );
#endif
    assert(pEngine);
    DXCall(pEngine->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMaster, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_CHANNELS, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_SAMPLERATE));
    assert(pMaster);
    DWORD dwChannelMask;
    DXCall(pMaster->GetChannelMask(&dwChannelMask));
    DXCall(X3DAudioInitialize(dwChannelMask, X3DAUDIO_SPEED_OF_SOUND, X3DInstance));
    assert(X3DInstance);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(1000.f));
    ZeroMemory(&mListener, sizeof(X3DAUDIO_LISTENER));
    mListener.pCone = (X3DAUDIO_CONE*)&Listener_DirectionalCone;
}
```

Here is the play sound buffer method

```
void SoundSystem::PlaySoundBuffer(std::shared_ptr<Sound>& s, uint32_t loop)
{
const std::lock_guard lock(mMutex);

if (activeChannelSoundPtrs.size() > 180) return;

s->PlaySoundEffect(loop);

auto it = std::find_if(idleChannelSoundPtrs.begin(), idleChannelSoundPtrs.end(),
    [&s](const std::unique_ptr<ChannelSound>& pChan) -> bool
    {
        auto& f1 = pChan->GetFormat();
        auto& f2 = s->GetFormat();

        return
            (f1.nChannels == f2.nChannels
                && f1.wBitsPerSample == f2.wBitsPerSample
                && f1.nAvgBytesPerSec == f2.nAvgBytesPerSec
                && f1.nSamplesPerSec == f2.nSamplesPerSec
                && f1.wFormatTag == f2.wFormatTag
                && f1.cbSize == f2.cbSize
                && f1.nBlockAlign == f2.nBlockAlign);
    }
);

if (it == idleChannelSoundPtrs.end()) {
    activeChannelSoundPtrs.push_back(std::make_unique<ChannelSound>(*this, s->GetFormat()));
    activeChannelSoundPtrs.back()->PlaySoundEffect(s, loop);
}
else
{
    activeChannelSoundPtrs.push_back(std::move(*it));
    idleChannelSoundPtrs.erase(it);
    activeChannelSoundPtrs.back()->PlaySoundEffect(s, loop);
}
}
```

Here is the sound buffer on buffer end method:

```
__declspec(nothrow) void __stdcall SoundSystem::ChannelSound::VoiceCallback::OnBufferEnd(void* pBufferContext)
{
const std::lock_guard lock(SoundSystem::Get().mMutex);

ChannelSound& chan = *(ChannelSound*)pBufferContext;
if (chan.pSound) {
    chan.Stop();
    chan.pSound->RemoveChannel(chan);
    chan.pSound.reset();
    DXCall(chan.pSource->SetVolume(1.f));
    DXCall(chan.pSource->SetFrequencyRatio(1.f));
    chan.xaBuffer.LoopCount = 0;
    SoundSystem::Get().DeactivateChannelSound(chan);
} 
}
```

And here is the update method that is called once per frame from the main thread

```
void SoundSystem::Update()
{
const std::lock_guard lock(mMutex);

XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS details{};
ZeroMemory(&details, sizeof(XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS));
pMaster->GetVoiceDetails(&details);

for (auto& channel : activeChannelSoundPtrs) {
    assert(channel);
    assert(channel->pSound);

    X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS DSPSettings{};
    ZeroMemory(&DSPSettings, sizeof(X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS));
    std::unique_ptr<FLOAT32[]> matrix = std::make_unique<FLOAT32[]>(channel->pSound->mFormat.nChannels * details.InputChannels);
    ZeroMemory(matrix.get(), channel->pSound->mFormat.nChannels * details.InputChannels * sizeof(FLOAT32));
    DSPSettings.SrcChannelCount = channel->pSound->mFormat.nChannels;
    DSPSettings.DstChannelCount = details.InputChannels;
    DSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients = matrix.get();
    DSPSettings.pDelayTimes = nullptr;

    X3DAudioCalculate(
        X3DInstance, &mListener, &channel->pSound->Emitter,
        X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_MATRIX | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_DOPPLER | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_DIRECT,
        &DSPSettings);

    // Apply X3DAudio generated DSP settings to XAudio2
    DXCall(channel->pSource->SetFrequencyRatio(DSPSettings.DopplerFactor * channel->pSound->mPitch));
    DXCall(channel->pSource->SetOutputMatrix(pMaster, DSPSettings.SrcChannelCount, DSPSettings.DstChannelCount, DSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients));
    XAUDIO2_FILTER_PARAMETERS FilterParametersDirect = {
        LowPassFilter, // Filter type (e.g., low-pass)
        2.0f * sinf(X3DAUDIO_PI / 6.0f * DSPSettings.LPFDirectCoefficient), // Cutoff frequency
        1.0f // Resonance or other filter parameters
    };
    DXCall(channel->pSource->SetOutputFilterParameters(pMaster, &FilterParametersDirect));
}

if (mMixToBattle && mBattleMusic && mBGM) {
    if (mBGMVolume > 0.f) {
        if (!mBattleMusic->IsPlaying() || mBattleMusic->GetQueuedBuffers() == 0) {
            PlayMusicStream(mBattleMusic, true);
        }
        mBGMVolume -= TimeManager::GetInstance()->DeltaTimeF();
        mBattleVolume += TimeManager::GetInstance()->DeltaTimeF();

        mBGMVolume = glm::clamp(mBGMVolume, 0.f, 1.f);
        mBattleVolume = glm::clamp(mBattleVolume, 0.f, 1.f);

        if (mBGMVolume <= 0.f) {
            mMixToBattle = false;
            mBGM->Stop();
        }
        else {
            mBGM->SetVolume(mBGMVolume);
            mBattleMusic->SetVolume(mBattleVolume);
        }
    }
}
if (mMixToBGM && mBattleMusic && mBGM) {
    if (mBattleVolume > 0.f) {
        if (!mBGM->IsPlaying() || mBGM->GetQueuedBuffers() == 0) {
            PlayMusicStream(mBGM, true);
        }
        mBattleVolume -= TimeManager::GetInstance()->DeltaTimeF();
        mBGMVolume += TimeManager::GetInstance()->DeltaTimeF();

        mBGMVolume = glm::clamp(mBGMVolume, 0.f, 1.f);
        mBattleVolume = glm::clamp(mBattleVolume, 0.f, 1.f);

        if (mBattleVolume <= 0.f) {
            mMixToBGM = false;
            mBattleMusic->Stop();
        }
        else {
            mBattleMusic->SetVolume(mBattleVolume);
            mBGM->SetVolume(mBGMVolume);
        }
    }
}
}
```

If I remove the update code the game does not crash. I omitted the code for the streaming music part. Let me know if you need to see that too as it is a lot of code for it.

Also after getting the pdbs from the windows servers I was able to get a call stack if it is useful to someone:

[image: stack]

Comment: without code we can't help. Access Violation can have many causes. writing to a nullptr, writing to a dangling pointer. Most likely your memory management is at fault.
Do you use the Debug DLL and have an XAudio2 Engine that has Debug enabled?

Comment: [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536492/950488) covers some reasons & solutions for release mode crashes that don't happen in debug build. As mentioned in a comment there, turning off optimizations may allow you to debug the release build to help track down the error. Beyond that, we need a verified minimal example in order to help spot a problem.

Comment: @Raildex I updated the post with some of my sound system code

Comment: I've added some bounty for anyone who can help me with this. I can also provide more source code

Comment: A minimal program that reproduces the problem could allow someone else to reproduce this and debug it.

Comment: Hi @Adam , thank you for the comment. Sadly the problem happens during playing for several minutes (1 - 20) and during heavy scenes, so I really don't know how to reproduce the problem using a minimal program, and if I knew I would be possibly capable of fixing it.

Comment: There's a couple more bits of info that might help debugging this. When it crashes:
- Open a memory window (Debug->Windows->Memory), and point it at the destination address of that access violation (0x000002AE0FF1B8A8 in the example in the question).
- Seeing a few lines of disassembly (the ones around the yellow arrow showing the current instruction) of the function at the top of the callstack might help. You'll probably need to disable "just my code" in Visual Studio to make it show that, and then go to Debug->Windows->Disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

The top of the call stack is `ResampleLinearFroMin16MonoSse2()`, and it's crashed reading a non-null memory address. That address is only 8-byte aligned, so it's probably not the start of a memory allocation.

I'd guess that that function would be reading one of your buffers full of 16-bit mono samples and is re-sampling them.

I'm guessing that you might have deleted the data that it's in the middle of playing. As a simple test you could try just commenting out all of the code that deletes them. You could also try logging all XAudio related memory allocations and frees.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already tried that yesterday but still getting the same error. I commented out the code that I have in my original question on the function OnBufferEnd, that is being called at the end of a playing buffer, where I move the channel pointer to another (idle) collection to be reused.

Comment: But to be honest, you are either correct about memory corruption during play or like other sources that I found online say that I must be aligning the data to 2 bytes (OGG files 16 bit) which I don't know how to do

Comment: If you want to align a memory allocation, one option is `_aligned_malloc()` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=msvc-170

However, even using `operator new[]` to allocate memory should give you something that's at least 16-byte aligned on 64-bit Windows (although if your program is 32-bit the default is 8-byte alignment).

Comment: Hi @Adam Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay. I've been trying all sorts of things to get rid of the bug including your suggestions with the aligned memory but still the same problem